# php dynamic pagination logical error

Tags: php, html, mysql, pagination

I am developing a page where a user can enter the limit of the table in pagination. While I am doing this the data I enter is taken and query is performed according to that. But as I click on another page of that table the value is reset to default which I set to 5 here.

```
<?php  session_start(); ?>
<a href="recordentry.php">Submit New record</a><br><br>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="dlimit">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php 
$database = 'test';
require 'connection.php';
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $limit = 5;
}
else 
{ 
    $dlimit = $_POST['dlimit'];
    $limit = $dlimit;
}
@$id = $_GET['id'];

 if($id==""||$id==null)
 {
    $page=0;
 }
 else
 {
 $page = ($id*$limit)-$limit;
}
    $qq ="select * from record limit $page,$limit";
    $result = $link -> query($qq);
?>
<table border="1"><th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>qualification</th>
        <th>address</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) 
    {
?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->id ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->user_name ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->qualification ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->address ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php 
}
?>
</table>
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM record";
    $result = $link -> query($query);
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $rr = $rows/$limit;
    $rr = ceil($rr);
    for ($i=1; $i<=$rr ; $i++) { 
?>
      <a href="recordfetch.php?id=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo @$i;?>&nbsp;</a>  
<?php    
}
mysqli_close($link)
?>
```

Run the above code and check. If my words are not clear to you.

Comment: How should we run your code without the missing files and the database structure and so on..?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the $_POST data is missing. You click on the link, so the new page will open without POST infos.

You can change this, if you switch to GET instead of POST. You can add the GET parameter to your `<a href="">` Tag.

For example
`<a href="pagination.php?page=5&dlimit=100`

Also try to avoid the `@`error suppression and don't pass the $_POST/$_GET Vars directly to your sql string. Bad people could use it for SQL Injections

Comment: i tried it but as I replace **post** with **get** a loop to infinity begins.
there is two link in the file one at beginning where data is entered in database and then connection where my database connection data is stored. and the recordfetch.php is the file itself.

SQL structure for demo I used is **user_name** , **qualification** ,  and **address**

Hope this info will help to resolve this issue

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Atm. I think that you just want a user defined LIMIT. Therefore I would add the GET to the link

Comment: ok I am missing one get. But again same thing no matter on which page I am, as I enter the limit system takes it and process, after that as I changes the page again it start showing the default value which is 5

Comment: to understand it correctly: you have a form where you can set the number of elements on a page. If you sumbit it, the page will reload with <NUMBER OF THE FORM> elements on this page. Also you want to have a pagination where you can switch between the number of pages in relation to your <NUMBER OF THE FORM> variable, correct?

Comment: yes, value I am entering on page 1 is not moving to other page.
https://snag.gy/Vl5yaR.jpg
https://snag.gy/qp6kx7.jpg

See the URL of two pages dlimit is the variable where value of the text field is stored.

Answer (score 0):

So I got the answer for my question. I am posting it here if anyone need it on later basis.

```
 <a href="recordentry.php">Submit New record</a><br><br>
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" name="dlimit">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php 
$database = 'test';
require 'connection.php';
if(empty($_GET['dlimit']) && !isset($_GET['submit']) && empty($_GET['n']))
{
    $limit = 5;
    global $limit;
}
else 
{ 
    if (isset($_GET['dlimit'])) 
    {
        $limit = $_GET['dlimit'];
    }
    else
    {
        @$limit = $_GET['n'];
    }
    global $limit;
}
if(!isset($_GET['submit'])&& empty($_GET['n']))
{
    $n=5;
    global $n;

}
else
{
    if(empty($_GET['dlimit']))
    {
        $n=$_GET['n'];
    }
    else
    {
        $n=$_GET['dlimit'];
    }
    global $n;

}

@$id = $_GET['id'];

 if($id==""||$id==null)
 {
    $page=0;
 }
 else
 {
 $page = ($id*$limit)-$limit;
}
    $qq ="select * from record limit $page,$limit";
    $result = $link -> query($qq);
?>
<table border="1"><th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>qualification</th>
        <th>address</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) 
    {
?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->id ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->user_name ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->qualification ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->address ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php 
}
?>
</table>
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['submit']) && empty($_GET['n'])) {
    $n = 5;
    global $n;
}
else
{
    if (empty($_GET['dlimit'])) {
        $n = $_GET['n'];
    }
    else
    {
        $n = $_GET['dlimit'];
    }
    global $n;
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM record";
    $result = $link -> query($query);
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $rr = $rows/$limit;
    $rr = ceil($rr);
    for ($i=1; $i<=$rr ; $i++) { 
?>
      <a href="recordfetch.php?id=<?php echo $i; ?>&& n=<?php echo @$n; ?>"><?php echo @$i;?>&nbsp;</a>  
<?php    
}
mysqli_close($link)
?>
```

**Again I am mentioning here that files which I included here are just connection where I filled my connection details and other is my record entry file where data is entered by the user.**